# How to Install ROUGE In Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, installation, perl-module

Although there is good description of how to Set Up [ROUGE evaluation](http://kavita-ganesan.com/rouge-howto) , i could not get any place where the installation was described completely.

Comment: yes this is not a question but share your knowledge, Q&A-style.

Comment: @dibyendu: But this isn't a question.

Comment: Yes this is not a question but never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site

Comment: It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better :)

Comment: If you rephrased this as a question then it would be fine. But currently, it's not a question and is therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the trick is in the successful installation of the perl modules.

I am  providing the download and installing links as well.

1. First Download [ROUGE](http://www.berouge.com/Pages/DownloadROUGE.aspx).
2. Install [perl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425427/how-to-install-perl-php-mysql-and-ruby-packages-on-ubuntu).
3. Install [Synaptic Package manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager) for installing XML::DOM

   ```
   libxml-dom-perl
   ```

The good thing is that synaptic package manager will install extra Perl modules that are required by XML::DOM. Many times people get stuck at how to install the XML::DOM.

Hope this helps. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Tried lot of times with apt-get and failed. Hope this helps others with such experience.

Comment: Also if you get any error in out put you can see my answer for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401114/rouge-evaluation-method-gives-zero-value

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the Java version of ROUGE if the perl version does not work. The documentation and download links can be found here: http://kavita-ganesan.com/content/rouge-2.0